# Error when calling API via React Native iOS app - NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"

Tags: laravel, xcode, amazon-web-services, react-native, axios

I'm struggling with an error when I try to hit my backend API in my React Native iOS app. The error only occurs when I test on my device - it does not occur on Simulator on my Mac. It also does not occur when I connect the app to my local backend API.

The error is (I've redacted the backend API hostname) -

```
Task <59435D75-1732-40F3-AAE1-FE05249D28A1>.<1> finished with error [-1000] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=22, NSUnderlyingError=0x280a92d60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1000 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x2826ac5a0 [0x1ebd75d10]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb364cf7580000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=22, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <59435D75-1732-40F3-AAE1-FE05249D28A1>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <59435D75-1732-40F3-AAE1-FE05249D28A1>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxx.com/api/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxx.com/api/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Has anyone else experienced this before? I'm struggling to figure it out.

For info - I'm using the Axios library in the app and the backend API is a Laravel app hosted on an AWS EC2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution to this @Phil ?